# Mongodb natural sort on non-capped collections, how wrong is it?

Tags: mongodb

The mongo docs explains that natural sort is not guaranteed to work in non-capped collections

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order

But how wrong is it? For non critical usecases, a .1% inaccuracy is totally fine, especially if there are performance / size savings.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the use case? Logging or mission critical trajectory calculations for spaceships (where in the latter case 0.1% can actually make you miss your destination, even if your calculations were fast)

Comment: @Matt, obviously it's not mission critical...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using the $natural sort (order) for non-capped collections.

The meaning of $natural is dramatically different on a capped collection and a normal one (where updates/removes can occur). With a regular collection the order of the documents may change over time.

If you want to return the documents in order of insertion then the $natural index (not really an index) is not useful on anything but a capped collection. This is cause only capped collections require that no documents can be removed or moved within the collection.

Comment: Do you know what causes the natural order to change?

Comment: As I said, the natural order is not natural, but the order on disk. If  you remove a document from a collection, that hole can be filled by a new document, for example.

Comment: Another example is replication: when a secondary node in a replica set does its initial sync, it may write the data to disk in a 100% different order from the primary.

Answer (score 0):

As said and documented: you have no guarantees and therefore no numbers can be given.

Comment: I don't need a guarantee, if there's some way to tell when the order would be messed up then I might be able to figure out possible 'typical' error rate, at least for one specific usecase